# Potassium Ethoxide Synthesis: Does the Reaction Involve Radical Processes?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, radicals, alkali-metals, valence

Can Potassium Ethoxide be obtained by reacting the alcohol with metallic potassium?  Considering that potassium, as a group one metal, has only one valence electron, would this reaction therfore involve a radical process?

Comment: It is a common practice to let alkali metals react with alcohols as weak acids to get rid of remnants,  as the reaction is much slower than with water.  $\ce{2 M + ROH -> 2 ROM + H2}$. The reaction involves free solvated electrons, similarly as reaction with water or liquid ammonia. Electrons then reduce alcohol to hydrogen and alkoxide.

Answer (score -1):

The reaction can be very dramatic. Sodium metal reacts smoothly with dry ethanol generating hydrogen gas. Potassium reacts violently bouncing around on the surface. I recommend reacting potassium in small amounts under a N2 atmosphere.

Reaction of most active metals with water or acid most likely goes thru one electron transfers to give hydrogen atoms that then react further usually to form H2 molecules.

I worked for a company that made pressure transducers that were filled with silicone oil with a thin flexible stainless steel diaphragm that was in contact with the process. They had an interesting failure mode. They filled with H2 gas at eventually high pressure. This was first noticed in refineries in hydrogenation processes and was dismissed as H2 migration thru the steel from the high pressure in the process and was partially solved by using lower nickel stainless and a competitor actually gold plated theirs. Then failures happened in sugar beet plants and breweries in processes that had no H2 gas. The reaction was fastest with the corrosion resistant high nickel steels. What was happening was that the transducers were in electrical contact with steel tanks the tanks were corroding and the hydrogen was generated on the SS diaphragms and migrating thru the metal as H atoms and forming H2 inside with no means of returning. This was reproduced in the lab using iron and zinc in acid in contact with the transducers. Problem solved by using the lowest nickel SS suitable and carefully insulating the transducers from the metal tank. The evidence for a one electron reaction even for the divalent metals is that hydrogen transferred thru the metal extremely rapidly at very low hydrogen pressures and even at high inside pressures it did not transfer back.